# How can i get List along with child list where child list having some condition in NHibernate

Tags: c#, nhibernate, queryover

I had written a Query in NHibernate as below:

```
var queryResult = CurrentSession.QueryOver()
                                .Where(r => r.StatusId == 1)
                                .JoinQueryOver(a => a.ActorList)
                                .Where(s=>s.IsActor==1)
                                .List()
                                .Distinct()
                                .ToList();
```

I am trying to retrieve only `Where(s=>s.IsActor==1)`, But It Is Getting Records
`Where(s=>s.IsActor==0)` also...

How can I get only `IsActor==1` records?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Must it be Queryover? Could you use LINQ?

Comment: it must be queryover only

Comment: It may be easier to just run two queries here, one for the top level objects and another for the associated collections...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to specify a predicate in the join, so that it is applied to the join not the top where:

(will look something like `...LEFT JOIN actor on actor.Id = p.ActorId AND IsActor = 1`)

```
Actor actorAlias = null;
var queryResult = CurrentSession.QueryOver()
                   .Where(r => r.StatusId == 1)
                   .Left.JoinQueryOver(r => r.ActorList, () => actorAlias, a => a.IsActor==1)
                   .List()
                   .Distinct()
                   .ToList();
```